# Retain form values after page redirect, show these values in new Form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have written the following code, now what i want is the value of text field 'name' in next `html` but it should not passed as query string.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
            location.replace("newHtml.html");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="name"></input><!--value needs to be retained-->
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Replace Page</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [HTML5 local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

This will store the values in the browser(***must support HTML5***) and you can grab the values anytime you want..!!! This will only be cleared once the browser is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a form tag and pass the information via POST instead of GET (so that it's not a query string), but you'd have to use a little PHP in the destination to use the values (with $_POST)

```
<form action="https://example.com/newHtml.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Replace Page</button>
</form>
```

You can put this in the destination (e.g. inside the `<body>` tag) and manipulate with html. Here I also use htmlspecialchars to convert things like `&`,`"`,`'`,`<`,`>` so they won't mess with the html:

```
<body>
<p>Your name is <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?></p>
</body>
```